# Inputs are are not able to force to DUT in Testbench

Tags: verilog

I have written tb in verilog. My testbench inputs are going at high impedance i.e. zz. My  dut is not able to force stimulus.Please  help me as I m not able detect the problem in my testbench.

```
module_tb()

 reg [47:0]  data_out_1;  
top_design uut1(
           //inputs

            .clock(clk),
           .reset(rst),
           .data_in(data_i),
           .dcsel(dcsel),
           .xlat(xlat),
           .blank(),
           .RD(read),
           ///OUTPUTS
           .Data_out(data_out_tb));
 initial 
       begin
      //inialize 
inputs

      #1 rst=0
      exp_case_2a(data_out_1);
      exp_case_2b(data_out_1);
      #100000 $finish;
       end
 task   operation_1;

      reg [47:0] data_out_1;
      begin
     exp_case_2a(data_out_1);
      end
   endtask 

   task   operation_2;

      reg  [47:0]  data_out_1;
      begin
     exp_case_2b(data_out_1);
      end
   endtask 

 task exp_case_2a;

      reg data_i;
      reg reset;
      reg read;
      reg dcsel;
      reg xlat;
      output [47:0] data_o;
      begin
         repeat(47)begin@(posedge clk)
       data_i = 1;
        reset = 0;
        read = 0;
        dcsel = 0;
        xlat = 0;
        data_o = Data_out;
         end    
     @(posedge clk)
       begin
          data_i = 0;
          reset = 0;
          dcsel = 0;
          xlat = 1;
          read = 1;
          data_o = Data_out;
       end

         #5250  compare_data_2(data_out_tb); 
      end   
   endtask // exp_case_2a


   task exp_case_2b;

      reg  data_i;
      reg  reset;
      reg  read;
      reg  dcsel;
      reg  xlat;
      output [47:0] data_o;
      begin
     repeat(47)begin @(posedge clk)
       data_i = 1;
        reset   = 0;
        read = 0;
        dcsel = 0;
        xlat = 0;
        data_o = Data_out;          
     end
     @(posedge clk)
       begin
          data_i = 0;
          reset = 0;
          read = 0;
          dcsel = 0;
          xlat = 1;
          data_o = Data_out;
       end   
     #5250   compare_data_2(data_out_tb);
      end       
   endtask 

 /* ...........  SCORE-BOARD..............  

   task compare_data_1;               
      input [47:0] exp_data;

      begin        
     if(exp_data == `comp_data_1 )
       begin
          $display("test passed 0");
          -> error; 
       end
     else
       begin
          $display("test failed 0");  
          -> error; 
          err_cnt_1 = err_cnt_1 + 1;
       end // else:
      end
   endtask
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there are other issues, your basic problem is that the (implicit) wires that you have connected to your unit under test are not driven by anything.

The `reg` variables with the same names that you have declared within each `task` are local to that task, and have nothing to do with the top-level wires.

If you want the task to be able to read and/or drive wires in the top level, you need to pass those connections as arguments to the task, and declare them as inputs and/or outputs within the task itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I tried out passing for eg  exp_case_2a(data_i_g,rst_g,read_g,dcsel_g,xlat_g,data_out_1); inside "task operation_1 " and declare it as input /output .But still its not working.

Comment: I think I would suggest at this point that you write a simple version of your testbench *without* tasks, get it working the way you want, and then organize it into tasks so that it can be extended.